# Grab manufacturer logo by 'id' or 'name' and display in table - Laravel 8 - aJax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Morning all.

I have created a vehicle database with somewhat detailed information like engine type, fuel, transmission, manufacturer and so on...

I started out by selecting the logo for each entry and soon realized that I will end up with a folder full of the same logos just named differently by timestamp.

I am therefore trying to create a process of manually uploading all the manufacturer logos into an assets folder then when I input the 'Manufacturer Name' it will use the information to pull the relevant logo from public/storage/assets.

My Vehicle Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory; /**  Name of columns fillable */
    protected $table = 'vehicles';
    protected $fillable = [
        'make',
        'model_name',
        'version',
        'powertrain',
        'trans',
        'fuel',
        'model_year',
        'image',
        'created_at'

    ];
};
```

My VehiclesController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Vehicle;
use Illuminate\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\CreateVehiclesTable;

class VehiclesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    /** Handle insert */

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // print_r($_POST);
        // print_r($_FILES);
        // // }


        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filename = time(). '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->storeAs('public/images', $filename);



        // handle insert vehicle ajax request
        $vehicle = Vehicle::create(
            [
            'make' => $request->make,
            'model_name' => $request->model_name,
            'version' => $request->version,
            'powertrain' => $request->powertrain,
            'trans' => $request->trans,
            'fuel' => $request->fuel,
            'model_year' => $request->model_year,
            'image' => $filename
            ]
        );

        return response()->json($vehicle);
    }

    // FETCH ALL AJAX REQUEST

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::all(); //Could be model or controller...
        $output = '';
        if ($vehicles->count() > 0) {
            $output .= '<table class="table table-striped table-sm text-center align-middle" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="tbl-head">ID</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Image</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Make</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Model</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Derivative</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Powertrain</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Transmission</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Fuel Type</th>
                        <th class="tbl-head">Model Year</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
            foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
                $output .= '<tr class="tbl exp_tbl">
                    <td>'.$vehicle->id.'</td>
                    <td><img src="./storage/images/'.$vehicle->image.'"  class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->make.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->model_name.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->version.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->powertrain.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->trans.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->fuel.'</td>
                    <td>'.$vehicle->model_year.'</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" id="'.$vehicle->id.'" class="text-success mx-2 editIcon" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="editVehicleModal"><i class="bi-pencil-square h4"></i></a>

                        <a href="#" id="'.$vehicle->id.'" class="text-danger mx-1 delete-icon"><i class-"bi-trash h4"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
            }
            $output .= '</tbody></table>';
            echo $output;
        } else {
            echo '<h1 class="text-center text-secondary my-5">No vehicles in the database!</h1>';
        }
    }

    public function time($time)
    {
        $time->Carbon::now();
    }
}
```

My Migration file

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateManufacturersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('manufacturers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('manu_logo');
            $table->string('manu_name');
            $table->timestamps('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('manufacturers');
    }
}
```

I am under the impression that I will need to generate a new model and use the present VehiclesController to pull the logo from the manufacturers model.

I think I'm getting a little confused and would appreciate any help, if anymore information is needed please dont hesitate to ask

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several solutions:

a) use manufacturer **id** to get access to logo;

b) use manufacturer name to provide logo, but in this case you need to load manufacturer relation every time;

c) use `image` field to provide logo url based on manufacturer when creating `Vehicle` model (in other variants you don't need `image` field in `Vehicle` model **or** it can be used to provide vehicle photo not the manufacturer logo);

d) upload logo when creating/updating `Manufacturer` to use it (based on your manufacturer table migration - **this is the one you want**).

### so

a) steps:

1. upload bunch of logos into `public/logo` folder with relevant to car **manufacturer** `id` like 1.png, 2.png etc in whatever way you want (either manually or with some form with upload request)
2. in your `Vehicle` model create getter to get access to logo url
3. in controller use created in step 2 getter to provide displaying of associated logo

```php
// Vehicle Model
public function getLogoUrlAttribute() {
  $path = "logo/$this->make.png";
  return Storage::exists($path) ? Storage::url($path) : '';
}

// controller fetchAll() method
...
  <td><img src="$vehicle->logo_url"  class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
...
```

---

b) steps:

1. upload bunch of logos into `public/logo` folder with relevant to car **manufacturer** `name` like wv.png, audi.png etc in whatever way you want (either manually or with some form with upload request)
2. in your `Vehicle` model create getter to get access to logo url
3. in controller use created in step 2 getter to provide displaying of associated logo

```php
// Vehicle Model
public function getLogoUrlAttribute() {
  if (!$this->relationLoaded('manufacturer') {
    return '';
  }
  $name = $this->manufacturer-> manu_name;
  $path = "logo/$name.png";
  return Storage::exists($path) ? Storage::url($path) : '';
}

// controller fetchAll() method
...
  <td><img src="$vehicle->logo_url"  class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
...
```

---

c) steps:

1. upload bunch of logos into `public/logo` folder with relevant to car **manufacturer** `id` like 1.png, 2.png etc in whatever way you want (either manually or with some form with upload request)
2. when creating new vihecle set path to logo into `image` field

```php
// store() method
/* you don't need this anymore 
$file = $request->file('image');
$filename = time(). '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->storeAs('public/images', $filename);*/
  $path = Storage::exists('logo/$request->make.png') ?  "logo/$request->make.png" : '';
  $vehicle = Vehicle::create(
     [
       'make' => $request->make,
       'model_name' => $request->model_name,
       'version' => $request->version,
       'powertrain' => $request->powertrain,
       'trans' => $request->trans,
       'fuel' => $request->fuel,
       'model_year' => $request->model_year,
       'image' => $path
     ]
  );

// fetchAll() method
...
<td><img src="Storage::url($vehicle->image)"  class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
...
```

of make it even better

```php
//Vehicle model
public function getLogoUrlAttribute() {
  return Storage::url($this->image);
}

// fetchAll() method
...
<td><img src="$vehicle->logo_url" class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
...
```

---

d) steps:

1. when creating `Manufacturer` you uploading its logo (save it with whatever you want name as it will be tied by path)
2. get logo url from preloaded `manufacturer` relation

```php
// ManufacturerController
public function store() {
  // create new manufacturer and store provided logo image
}

// Vehicle model
public function manufacturer() {
  return $this->hasOne(Manufacturer::class, 'make', 'id');
}

// Manufacturer model
public function getLogoUrlAttribute() {
  return Storage::url("logs/$this->manu_logo.png");
}

// vehicle controller
public function fetchAll() {
  // note preloading manufacturer relation
  $vehicles = Vehicle::with('manufacturer')->get();
...
  <td><img src="" . $vehicle->manufacturer->logo_url class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
...
}
```

and just to be sure avoiding n+1 request problem i'd suggest still use getter in `Vehicle` model for logo

```php
// adding to Vehicle model
public function getLogoUrlAttribute() {
  if (!$this->relationLoaded('manufacturer') {
    return '';
  }
  $name = $this->manufacturer->manu_logo;
  $path = "logo/$name.png";
  return Storage::exists($path) ? Storage::url($path) : '';
}
// fetchAll() method
...
  <td><img src="$vehicle->logo_url" class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
...
```

---

---

some thoughts about your `fetchAll()` method:
i'd suggest you to let [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#main-content) build page for you - this will make controller nice and clear

```php
public function fetchAll() {
  // note preloading manufacturer relation
  $vehicles = Vehicle::with('manufacturer')->get();
  return view('vehicle-index', ['$vehicles'=>$vehicles]);
}
```

and all html stuff in `vehicle-index.blade.php` with much more pleasant to work with

```php
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta name="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta name="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta name="Expires" content="0" />

  <title>title</title>

  <!-- CSRF Token -->
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>

<body>
  @if ($vehicles->isEmpty())
  <h1 class="text-center text-secondary my-5">No vehicles in the database!</h1>
  @else
  <table class="table table-striped table-sm text-center align-middle">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tbl-head">ID</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Image</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Make</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Model</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Derivative</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Powertrain</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Transmission</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Fuel Type</th>
        <th class="tbl-head">Model Year</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tbl exp_tbl">
        <td>{{ $vehicle->id }}</td>
        <td><img src="{{ $vehicle->logo_url }}" class="img-thumbnail justify-content-sm-center rounded-circle"></td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->make }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->model_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->version }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->powertrain }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->trans }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->fuel }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->model_year }}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" id="{{ $vehicle->id }}" class="text-success mx-2 editIcon" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="editVehicleModal"><i class="bi-pencil-square h4"></i></a>

          <a href="#" id="{{ $vehicle->id }}" class="text-danger mx-1 delete-icon"><i class="bi-trash h4"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  @endif

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it is really informative, detailed and yet educational. I will be studying it in more detail so I can learn from my mistakes.

Kind Regards